# I am getting an error when trying to start an Smpp client using the JamaaTech Smpp library

Tags: c#, smpp

When I am trying to start an SMPP client,I am getting the following  at

```
JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.Networking.TcpIpSession.RaiseSessionClosedEvent(JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.Networking.SessionCloseReason, System.Exception)
   at JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.Networking.TcpIpSession.Receive(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
```

I am using th JamaaTech Smpp library on C#

It was connecting properly but now I am getting that error.

```
var client = new SMPPClient.SMPPClient(s);
var smppCl = client.GetSMPPClient();
connections.GetOrAdd(s.SMSCID.ToString(), smppCl);
await Task.Run(() => smppCl.Start());
```